# Error #2007, in AS3, but it traces the correct result, when var textfield is added, it displays Null in dynamic text box

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

When i tried to use var textField and String(), the result display null.What i posted below, it display Error #2007 Parameter text must be non-null. Trying to pass the echoed results from mysql through php on AS3, through a few dynamic text box.
But when i switch it to Trace(event.target.data), it shows the correct Data.

Here is my AS3 code

```
var Mend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/Autoresult.php");
Mend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;



var variablesss:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variablesss.nobed1 = result.text;
variablesss.LoZip=result2.text;
variabless.rangelow=result3.text;
Mend.data = variablesss;


var BLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
BLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
BLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,Candler);
BLoader.load(Mend);


// handler for the PHP script completion and return of status
 function Candler(event:Event){

    var seVariables: URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);     


     result.text=seVariables.nobed1;
    result2.text=seVariables.LoZip1;
     result3.text=seVariables.rangelow1;



}
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

include 'connect.php';


$_SESSION['username'];
$username=$_SESSION['username'];


$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Test WHERE username = '$username'")or die( mysqli_error($con));
$solutions = array();
$check_num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
        $solutions[0]=$row['nobed1'];
        $solutions[1]=$row['LoZip1'];
$solutions[2]=$row['rangelow1'];}




echo "nobed1=.$solutions[0]&LoZip1=.$solutions[1]&rangelow1=.$solutions[2]";



?>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: I experienced similiar problems due to the asynchronity of the requests in ActionScript, but binding to Event.COMPLETE should do the trick. Maybe for starting just try to use some coding convention to avoid things like "variabless.rangelow"..?

Comment: I am willing to try it, but not very sure how to, as i am very new to AS3 and php. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: You've said you trace `event.target.data` and it gets out correctly. Do trace post-conversion `seVariables.nobed1`, `seVariables.LoZip1`, `seVariables.rangelow1` and find out if any is null or undefined.

Comment: I managed to resolve it with another method. Just going to post my answer underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my problem, changing the php, and putting the result in a string, pass it through to AS3, then split up the answer and put them into the dynamic text box.

Here is my code.

```
function Candler(event:Event){

       var fromPhp:String = event.target.data;

     var errors:Array = fromPhp.split(",");

     trace(errors.length)     
     result.text= (errors[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/mg, ""));
     result2.text= (errors[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/mg, ""));
     result3.text= (errors[2].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/mg, ""));
     result4.text= (errors[3].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/mg, ""));
    }
```

Comment: Wonder why is the question voted down, when the the question is clearly listed, the detail is displayed, tried for hours before asking the question, posted the code in a clear manner above. Maybe because being new to coding is causing people to dislike these questions. Well i even figured the answer after 18 hours, and even posted my solution to aid others. Maybe i am breaching some of the rules that i am not noticed of.

Answer (score 0):

without looking into it too deeply, it seems like it might be a type miss-match.

you could try

```
var seVariables: URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data + "");
```

that way it is converted to text